# ActionBar search-results below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using the ActionBar searchview in conjunction with the OnQueryTextListener. The input text is recognized - so this part works fine.

How can I display the search results below the actionbar (just like google maps app) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Adding search suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchSuggestions) [developer.android.com]